# Apply $geoNear to find nearest latlong using aggregation in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

My documents in a collection looks like this -

```
{'_id' : 'Delhi1', 'loc' : [28.34242,77.656565] }
{'_id' : 'Delhi2', 'loc' : [27.34242,78.626523] }
{'_id' : 'Delhi3', 'loc' : [25.34242,77.612345] }
{'_id' : 'Delhi4', 'loc' : [28.34242,77.676565] }
```

I want to apply aggregation using pymongo, to find out relevant document based on input latlong. I have created the index on 'loc'. Here is what I have done so far -

```
pipeline = [{'$geoNear':{'near': [27.8787, 78.2342],
                     'distanceField': "distance",
                     'maxDistance' : 2000 }}]
db['mycollection'].aggregate(pipeline)
```

But this is not working for me ? How to correctly use this ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I created the '2dsphere' index in collection, and to use geoNear with 2dsphere we need to specify, spherical = True in the pipeline

```
pipeline = [{'$geoNear':{'near': [27.8787, 78.2342],
                 'distanceField': "distance",
                 'maxDistance' : 2000,
                 'spherical' : True }}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a few formatting mistakes: 1) neither the collection nor operators need parentheses or brackets, 2) logical operators are lowercase.

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: { coordinates: [ 27.8787 , 78.2342 ] },
            distanceField: "distance",
            maxDistance: 2000,
            spherical: true
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: No, in pymongo, we need to wrap collection name and operator name to wrap inside parenthesis, 2 - in python logical operators are Propercase

Comment: Most notably here the `near: { coordinates: [ 27.8787 , 78.2342 ] }` is invalid. The `"near"` option takes either a coordinates array "directly" or a GeoJSON Object `{ "type": "Point", "coordinates":  [ 27.8787 , 78.2342 ] }`. @userxxx answered there own question anyway with the addition of `"spherical": True`, which in Python is the correct form of "boolean values" being either `True` or `False`. Note the tags when reading questions ( not forgetting that pymongo is used both in the question title and body as well ). Python has "similar" syntax to JSON and JavasScript, with differences.